# Binary subtraction A0 - E4

Tags: binary

I have two numbers. The negative one is translated using 2's complement.

$$
a = 160_{10} = A0_{16} = 1010 0000_{2} \\
b = -28_{10} = E4_{16} = 1110 0100_{2}
$$

And I have to perform the following operation $a - b$. I use borrowing up to the very last bit, but then I have a situation like.

$$
\begin{matrix}
          & 0 & 1 \\
        - & 1 & 1 \\
          & ? & 0 \\
\end{matrix}
$$

Should I borrow from something imaginary? In decimal $1 - 3 = -2$, so the answer is $BC$, but how do you reason about the negative $2$ here?

Comment: $a$ is not $160_{10}$ in your representation, it is $-96_{10}$.

Comment: @TonyK good catch! I wonder if I should expand those into 2 bytes. Any other suggestions how to deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it. Sign-extend your operands one bit to the left, i.e. duplicate the most significant bit. Your operands are both negative, so they will become $1A0_{16}$ and $1E4_{16}$. Now perform $9$-bit subtraction, and simply throw away the final borrow. You get $1BC_{16}$.

Here the two top bits are the same, so you can just discard the top bit to get $BC_{16}=-68_{10}$ as your 2's complement answer.

If the two top bits are different, then overflow or underflow has occurred, and the 8-bit result is out by $\pm256$.

Answer (score 1):

Subtraction is always done with the smaller number being *subtracted from* the bigger number.

So if $b>a$,
$$a-b=-|b-a|$$

Perform $b-a$ and add the minus symbol.

Comment: But how do I _add_ the minus symbol? All I have is binary symbols.

Comment: @MorganWilde Then use 2's complement to convert it into its own negative inverse.

Comment: Are you saying that is how subtraction is performed _in practice_, by 2's complement processors? I am skeptical.

Answer (score 1):

So we have the following subtract problem:

$$a-b = 10100000_2 - 11100100_2$$

Whenever we arrive a point where we need to "borrow" like we do in normal subtraction, we simply change the top number to a $2$, as we do in normal subtraction where we borrow from the previous number and add $10$ to it.

Then, we must subtract $1$ from the number we "borrowed" from.

If you are still unclear, [this](http://www.basic-mathematics.com/subtraction-in-base-two.html) link might be able to help you.

Comment: The question asks, what do you do if you are still left with an outstanding borrow at the end of the computation?

Comment: @TonyK then you would end up with a negative answer

Comment: I don't think it's as simple as that.